# Add a column of proportions by factor level in a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame with a a "site" column, a "species" column, a "counts" column, plus other columns, and I need to create another column with proportions by "species" using "counts" data.

```
    site <- c(rep("site1",3), rep("site2",4), rep("site3",2))
    species <- c("sp1","sp2","sp3","sp1","sp2","sp3","sp4","sp2","sp4")
    counts <- c(4,10,22,1,13,23,4,3,1)
    data <- cbind(site,species,counts)
   site species counts   ...
1 site1     sp1      4
2 site1     sp2     10
3 site1     sp3     22
4 site2     sp1      1
5 site2     sp2     13
6 site2     sp3     23
7 site2     sp4      4
8 site3     sp2      3
9 site3     sp4      1
```

My desired data frame should have and added column with proportions by "species", like this:

```
   site species counts proportions_by_species   ...
1 site1     sp1      4                   0.80
2 site1     sp2     10                   0.38
3 site1     sp3     22                   0.49
4 site2     sp1      1                   0.20
5 site2     sp2     13                   0.50
6 site2     sp3     23                   0.51
7 site2     sp4      4                   0.80
8 site3     sp2      3                   0.11
9 site3     sp4      1                   0.20
```

Comment: Try `df %>% mutate(proportions_by_species = counts/sum(counts), .by = species)`. Btw, you probably want a data frame, so e.g. `df <- data.frame(site,species,counts)`

Comment: Don't use `cbind()` to merge multiple vectors of different types. That coerces all values to be the same type. In this case, all the numeric values are converted to character. You should use `data.frame(site, species, counts)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

site <- c(rep("site1",3), rep("site2",4), rep("site3",2))
species <- c("sp1","sp2","sp3","sp1","sp2","sp3","sp4","sp2","sp4")
counts <- c(4,10,22,1,13,23,4,3,1)
data <- data.frame(site,species,counts)

data <- data |> 
  group_by(species) |> 
  mutate(proportions_by_species = prop.table(counts))
```

Alternatively

```
data <- data |> 
  group_by(species) |> 
  mutate(proportions_by_species = counts/sum(counts))
```

Comment: Your prop.table is incorrect. You should have `prop.table(counts)` or even `proportions(counts)` not the one you have

Comment: Interesting use of base R's new pipe `|>` with dplyr and not the familiar tidyverse pipe `%>%`! Why not stay with base R using `transform` and `ave`?